# Reference counting for SWIG-ed C structs containing complex types doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: python, struct, swig

I came across an interesting discovery related to how SWIG handles reference counting of C structures that contain other structures as members.

I observed that my python SWIG objects were getting garbage collected before I was done using them in situations where I was storing data from structure sub-members into other python objects ( lists/dicts ).  After a fair bit of digging I discovered that SWIG-ed structure members did not seem to have their own independent reference counts even though the interpreter indicates they are "Swig Objects".  Therefore when I added the data from the structure sub-element to my list python had no knowledge that I had added a reference to this data.

I have created a simple case to demonstrate.  I SWIG-ed the following 3 structures:

**SWIG-ed C Structures:**

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned long source;      
    unsigned long destination; 
} message_header;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned long data[120];    
} message_large_body;


typedef struct
{
    message_header       header;
    message_large_body   body;
} large_message;
```

I then created a somewhat equivalent python class to compare the behavior to the purely SWIG-ed solution.

**Somewhat Equivalent Python Class**

```
class pyLargeMessage(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.header = bar.message_header()
        self.body = bar.message_large_body()
```

I then ran the following test in the interpreter.

**Python Interpreter Results**

```
>>> y = pyLargeMessage()
>>> y
<__main__.pyLargeMessage object at 0x06C5E6B0>
>>> y.header
<Swig Object of type 'message_header *' at 0x06C5E700>
>>> sys.getrefcount(y.header)
3
>>> z = [y.header]
>>> sys.getrefcount(y.header)
3
>>> z += [y.header]
>>> sys.getrefcount(y.header)
4
>>>
>>> y = bar.large_message()
>>> y
<Swig Object of type 'large_message *' at 0x06C668E0>
>>> y.header
<Swig Object of type 'message_header *' at 0x06C66B60>
>>> sys.getrefcount(y.header)
1
>>> z = [y.header]
>>> sys.getrefcount(y.header)
1
>>> z += [y.header]
>>> sys.getrefcount(y.header)
1
>>>
```

The Python implementation behaved as I expected, but the pure SWIG implementation did not.  Can someone explain what is going on here?

I've read through various sections of the SWIG documentation many many times and can't find anything that directly seems to explain this.  I've learned a lot more about how things work, but i can't find any clear explanation/workaround for the phenomenon above.

After thinking about it for a long while, re-reading the Structures and Classes, [Proxy classes](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Scripting_nn8) and [Structure Data Members](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_structure_data_members) sections over and over and looking at the generated wrapper code I still can't figure out why the reference counts aren't handled normally.

The generated C code calls `SWIG_NewPointerObj`, which eventually ( in most cases ) calls `PyObject_New`, which in turn should ( as the python documentation says ) return a new reference.

**Generated SWIG code for the get-er for the *header* member**

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_large_message_header_get(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  large_message *arg1 = (large_message *) 0 ;
  void *argp1 = 0 ;
  int res1 = 0 ;
  message_header *result = 0 ;

  if (args && PyTuple_Check(args) && PyTuple_GET_SIZE(args) > 0) SWIG_fail;
  res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(self, &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_large_message, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '" "large_message_header_get" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "large_message *""'"); 
  }
  arg1 = (large_message *)(argp1);
  result = (message_header *)& ((arg1)->header);
  resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(result), SWIGTYPE_p_message_header, 0 |  0 );
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Fwiw, `sys.getrefcount(y.header)` always returns 1 because every read of `y.header` returns a fresh new object.  Try instead to read `y.header` only once and save it in some variable.

Comment: I don't know SWIG well enough so this might be wrong, but I'd imagine that the Python objects are wrappers that live outside the C object itself: when you call `bar.large_message()` it both allocates the raw C memory for a `large_message` struct, and a wrapper Python object.  When this specific wrapper object goes away, it frees the raw C memory.  The `y.header` expression returns a new Python object pointing within the same raw C memory, but not keeping anything alive.  (I might be wrong somewhere, but that's how it works in CFFI, for example.)

Comment: Two great insights @ArminRigo.  Your second comment about it returning a reference into the same block of memory was my speculation as well.  I went ahead and wrote a simple helper function that returns the address of the underlying object as an unsigned int and it is the same for all instances of y.header (even though they have different Python Object addresses).  It seems though that a person should be able to get a copy of that memory into a new object without having to jump through too many hoops(typemaps), but perhaps I am wrong.  Perhaps I should answer my own question and ask a new one.

Comment: @ArminRigo - that looks like the answer to me. Perhaps you want to write it up. There are ways you could work around this within SWIG though.

Comment: @Flexo can you elaborate how you would get around this in SWIG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out the object returned by the getter for `header` and `body` is basically a lightweight proxy object that holds a pointer to memory for the `header`/`body` inside the `struct`. It doesn't own that memory (it's still "owned" by the `message` object itself, or the C library depending on how you've created it) and it's not a copy.

Even if it were a copy your call to `sys.getrefcount` would always return 1 still anyway - each call to the getter would be returning a new copy.

From the Python perspective if you want to ensure that you never have a dangling pointer there are two ways it could be fixed:

1. The getter returns a proxy for a copy of the `header`/`body` which owns the memory it points to.
2. The getter returns a proxy which holds a reference to the `message` itself, so that even if the `message` is released it's refcount can't hit 0 whilst there are proxy objects referring to parts of it.

I've put together an example of doing #2 with SWIG. Your header file remains unchanged, but the interface becomes:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(out) message_header * header %{
  // This expands to resultobj = SWIG_NewPointerObj(...) exactly as before:
  $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr($1), $1_descriptor, 0);
  // This sets a reference to the parent object inside the child
  PyObject_SetAttrString($result, "_parent", obj0);
%}

%include "test.h"
```

This is equivalent to saying:

```
z = y.header
z._parent = y
```

in Python.

With this in place we can now run:

```
y = test.large_message()
print(sys.getrefcount(y))
print(y.header)
z = [y.header]
print(sys.getrefcount(y))
z += [y.header]
print(sys.getrefcount(y))
```

Which as expected shows the reference count for `y` increasing with every sub-object proxy that is created. Thus the memory that they refer to can't be free'd prematurely (at least not by SWIG).

You can make that more generic and apply it to multiple types/members using `%apply`:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(out) SWIGTYPE * SUBOBJECT %{
  $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr($1), $1_descriptor, 0);
  PyObject_SetAttrString($result, "_parent", obj0);
  assert(obj0);
  // hello world
%}

%apply SWIGTYPE * SUBOBJECT { message_header * header };
%apply SWIGTYPE * SUBOBJECT { message_large_body * body };

%include "test.h"
```

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem.  I would imagine though that it would become cumbersome to use this solution if you were including a vast number of complex structures.  It makes me wonder though why this is not the default behavior in SWIG.  Swig knows about all the sub elements when it wraps them so why not keep better track of them and protect them from inadvertent garbage collection.

Comment: @tnerb123 SWIG mirrors the behaviour of C as close as possible. In this instance if you choose to keep a pointer around longer than the region of memory it points to the behaviour is undefined.